# dtruss broken in 10.13.x?

Tags: terminal, high-sierra

`dtruss` worked great in 10.12.x (after `csrutil disable`), but in 10.13 I've noticed that it no longer functions. For `sudo dtruss ls` we're only getting output like:

```
SYSCALL(args)        = return
```

Any news on what's happening here and how to get our necessary access to this back now?

---

Just for clarity, 10.12.6 yields much better results:

```
$ sudo dtruss ls
SYSCALL(args)        = return
open("/dev/dtracehelper\0", 0x2, 0x7FFF5D851A20)         = 3 0
ioctl(0x3, 0x80086804, 0x7FFF5D8519A8)       = 0 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
thread_selfid(0x3, 0x80086804, 0x7FFF5D8519A8)       = 13508 0
bsdthread_register(0x7FFFB4F6C080, 0x7FFFB4F6C070, 0x2000)       = 1073741919 0
ulock_wake(0x1, 0x7FFF5D85106C, 0x0)         = -1 Err#2
issetugid(0x1, 0x7FFF5D85106C, 0x0)      = 0 0
mprotect(0x1023B9000, 0x88, 0x1)         = 0 0
mprotect(0x1023BB000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x1023D1000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x1023D2000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x1023E8000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x1023E9000, 0x1000, 0x1)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x1023B9000, 0x88, 0x3)         = 0 0
mprotect(0x1023B9000, 0x88, 0x1)         = 0 0
getpid(0x1023B9000, 0x88, 0x1)       = 2137 0
stat64("/AppleInternal/XBS/.isChrooted\0", 0x7FFF5D850F28, 0x1)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/AppleInternal\0", 0x7FFF5D850FC0, 0x1)      = -1 Err#2
csops(0x859, 0x7, 0x7FFF5D850A50)        = 0 0
sysctl([CTL_KERN, 14, 1, 2137, 0, 0] (4), 0x7FFF5D850BA8, 0x7FFF5D850BA0, 0x0, 0x0)      = 0 0
ulock_wake(0x1, 0x7FFF5D850FD0, 0x0)         = -1 Err#2
csops(0x859, 0x7, 0x7FFF5D850330)        = 0 0
open_nocancel("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE\0", 0x0, 0x7)        = 3 0
fcntl_nocancel(0x3, 0x3, 0x0)        = 0 0
getrlimit(0x1008, 0x7FFF5D851FA8, 0x0)       = 0 0
fstat64(0x3, 0x7FFF5D851F68, 0x0)        = 0 0
read_nocancel(0x3, "1.1A\n\0", 0x1000)       = 2086 0
close_nocancel(0x3)      = 0 0
open_nocancel("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE\0", 0x0, 0x5)      = 3 0
fcntl_nocancel(0x3, 0x3, 0x0)        = 0 0
fstat64(0x3, 0x7FFF5D8520A8, 0x0)        = 0 0
fstat64(0x3, 0x7FFF5D851E98, 0x0)        = 0 0
lseek(0x3, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
lseek(0x3, 0x0, 0x0)         = 0 0
read_nocancel(0x3, "RuneMagAUTF-8\0", 0x1000)        = 4096 0
read_nocancel(0x3, "\0", 0x1000)         = 4096 0
read_nocancel(0x3, "\0", 0x1000)         = 4096 0
read_nocancel(0x3, "\0", 0x1000)         = 4096 0
read_nocancel(0x3, "\0", 0x1000)         = 4096 0
read_nocancel(0x3, "\0", 0x1000)         = 4096 0
read_nocancel(0x3, "@\004\031\0", 0xDE80)        = 56960 0
close_nocancel(0x3)      = 0 0
open_nocancel("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY\0", 0x0, 0x8)       = 3 0
fstat64(0x3, 0x7FFF5D8520C0, 0x8)        = 0 0
read_nocancel(0x3, "USD \n$\n.\n,\n3;3\n\n-\n2\n2\n1\n0\n1\n0\n1\n1\n\b\0", 0x22)        = 34 0
close_nocancel(0x3)      = 0 0
open_nocancel("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC\0", 0x0, 0x7)        = 3 0
fstat64(0x3, 0x7FFF5D8520C0, 0x7)        = 0 0
read_nocancel(0x3, ".\n,\n3;3\n@$\b\0", 0x8)         = 8 0
close_nocancel(0x3)      = 0 0
open_nocancel("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_TIME\0", 0x0, 0x4)       = 3 0
fstat64(0x3, 0x7FFF5D8520C0, 0x4)        = 0 0
read_nocancel(0x3, "Jan\nFeb\nMar\nApr\nMay\nJun\nJul\nAug\nSep\nOct\nNov\nDec\nJanuary\nFebruary\nMarch\nApril\nMay\nJune\nJuly\nAugust\nSeptember\nOctober\nNovember\nDecember\nSun\nMon\nTue\nWed\nThu\nFri\nSat\nSunday\nMonday\nTuesday\nWednesday\nThursday\nFriday\nSaturday\n%H:%M:%S\n%m/%d/%Y\n%a %b %e %X %Y\nAM\nP", 0x179)      = 377 0
close_nocancel(0x3)      = 0 0
open_nocancel("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES\0", 0x0, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF4)        = 3 0
fstat64(0x3, 0x7FFF5D8520C0, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF4)         = 0 0
read_nocancel(0x3, "^[yYsS].*\n^[nN].*\n(\0", 0x12)      = 18 0
close_nocancel(0x3)      = 0 0
ioctl(0x1, 0x4004667A, 0x7FFF5D8525EC)       = 0 0
ioctl(0x1, 0x40087468, 0x7FFF5D852C80)       = 0 0
getuid(0x1, 0x40087468, 0x7FFF5D852C80)      = 0 0
fstatat64(0xFFFFFFFE, 0x7FB70C402B98, 0x7FFF5D8524F8)        = 0 0
open_nocancel(".\0", 0x1000000, 0x0)         = 3 0
fchdir(0x3, 0x1000000, 0x0)      = 0 0
open_nocancel(".\0", 0x1000000, 0x0)         = 4 0
open_nocancel(".\0", 0x1100004, 0x0)         = 5 0
getattrlistbulk(0x5, 0x7FFF5D8524B8, 0x7FB70C819E00)         = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x5)      = 0 0
fchdir(0x4, 0x7FFF5D8524B8, 0x7FB70C819E00)      = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x4)      = 0 0
open_nocancel(".\0", 0x1100004, 0x3)         = 4 0
getattrlistbulk(0x4, 0x7FFF5D8524B8, 0x7FB70C819E00)         = 0 0
fstat64(0x4, 0x7FFF5D852350, 0x7FB70C819E00)         = 0 0
fchdir(0x4, 0x7FFF5D852350, 0x7FB70C819E00)      = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x4)      = 0 0
fchdir(0x3, 0x7FFF5D852350, 0x7FB70C819E00)      = 0 0
fchdir(0x3, 0x7FFF5D852350, 0x7FB70C819E00)      = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x3)      = 0 0
```

---

For anyone wondering if I have given ALL output, the following is ALL of the output for a folder I created called "test" with 6 "testing" files that I touched in it, executed as `root`:

```
hostname:test root# dtruss ls
testing     testing1    testing2    testing3    testing4    testing5
SYSCALL(args)        = return

hostname:test root#
```

Comment: After an initial hickup ("Invalid connection: com.apple.coresymbolicationd") the command `sudo dtruss ls` works in 10.13.4 here. You'd have to add some error details...

Comment: @klanomath there are no error details. I don't receive any at all, only that which I have shared above initially. I've tried this on TWO workstations, one running 10.13.4 and the other 10.13.5 beta. Please see my edit for you that shows the ENTIRE output while executing as root.